# Python: Compare elements of list with previous and next list of elements?

Tags: list, python-2.7, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of list, Let's say

```
list1 = [('A',[R]),
         ('B',['A','C']),
         ('C',['B']),
         ('B',[]),
         ('C',['D']),
         ('D',['C'])]
```

I'm trying to compare the  2nd elements of 2nd list  `['A','C']` with previous list first element `'A'` and the next list first element `['C']`. Likewise I want to compare all the 2nd elements of a list with previous and next list's first element. What I tried so far is

```
for i, items in enumerate (list1):
    for j in items[1]:
        if len(j)>0:
            if i !=0 and j == items[i-1][0]:
                print(j,items[i-1][0],'equal')
            if i < len(list1) and j==items[i+1][0]:
                print(j,items[i+1][0],'equal')
```

It shows error as `" tuple index out of range "`. Please correct me where I am going wrong ? 
The expected result is like

```
(A,A,equal)
(C,C,equal)
(B,B,equal)
(B,B,equal)
(D,D,equal)
(C,C,equal)
```

Comment: I guess the error is in this code items[i+1][0]

Comment: No, I checked it still says the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference items, you need to use list1

```
            if i !=0 and j == list1[i-1][0]:
                print(j,list1[i-1][0],'equal')
            if i -1 < len(list1) and j==list1[i+1][0]:
                print(j,list1[i+1][0],'equal')
```

Not sure what `if len(j)>0:` is all about as j is a character. Maybe just `if j:`

This might be easier code to understand.

```
for i, row in enumerate (list1): # Use the list1[1] list as the key data
    for item in row[1]: # Compare all items in this list with previous row first element
                        # and next row first element
        if i > 0: # Previous row
            if item == list1[i-1][0]: 
                print ('{} : {} equal'.format(item, list1[i-1][0]))
        if i < len(list1) - 1: # Next row
            if item == list1[i+1][0]: 
                print ('{} : {} equal'.format(item, list1[i+1][0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is below:

```
for i, items in enumerate(list1):
    for j in items[1]:
        if len(j)>0:
            if i!=0 and j==list1[i-1][0]:
                print(j,j,'equal')
            if i+1 < len(list1) and j==list1[i+1][0]:
                print(j,j,'equal')
```

You should be using `list1`, not `items` in the `if` statement.